# Disable React Native textinput but still can press enter / backspace key

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

As titled, is this possible?

I know can disable the React Native textinput by setting

```
editable={false}
```

but i need to have the functionality for other keys like Enter and Backspace to work at the same time. But i don't think that will work because setting `editable` as false effectively makes the input blur all the time, therefore cannot make attributes like `onKeyPress` and `onSubmitEditing` works.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

there is a trick that u can apply. you need to give it a constant value in the value attribute.

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("Useless Text");
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={""}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default UselessTextInput;
```

Comment: Not working.. i set the value as empty space (' ') but it still wouldn't work. After i set the editable as false, i try to press enter but nothing happens.

Comment: you have to remove the editable attribute or set it to true